# Improper use of a word - name of the action

Tags: word-usage

Does the act of using a word incorrectly (using it to describe something that in fact it does not describe) have a name?

For instance, saying 'My head literally exploded when I read this page' when the idea I want to communicate would require the usage of the phrase 'My head figuratively exploded when I read this page'

I want to know if there is a word that describes the action of using a word incorrectly, with a meaning that it does not have.

Comment: probably, "misuse"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Catechresis*** - the use of a word in a way that is not correct.

Other more specific terms are *malapropism* for errors with homonyms, *solecism* for grammatical errors, and apparently *eggcorn*-- new to me-- for creative invention like wheelbarrel instead of wheelbarrow, or mute point for moot point.